# Block IPs without receiving traffic

Tags: networking, firewall, routing, ddos, attacks

I'm hosting on OVH Game dedicated server, the bandwitdth of this server is 1gbp/s, I'm receinving attack from other OVH Servers and they are saturating the bandwidth with 1gbp/s.

OVH doesn't filter these attacks coming from other OVH Servers. Obviusly blocking these IPs with iptables / firewall software doesn't work because the traffic is still reaching my server.

OVH doesn't want to solve this and the attackers are not getting banned, Is there a solution to this? What can I do to to prevent that traffic reaching my server? is it possible ot null route IP OVH Ranges so that way the traffic doesn't reach my server and how can it be done?

Comment: Let me be clear: The problem is getting a DDOS attack from OTHER servers at the same hosting center? I am not sure under what jurisdiction you operate, but the Hoster IS liable in most jurisdictions to block that - in this case, servers reported as participating in a DDOS attack should be disconnected and the situation on those servers fixed. This is a technical issue that may have elevated to legal liability. Game servers MOST are preconfigured with an interface. This may have a leak and thus results in abuse? What is their support saying?

Comment: They said to wait for Abuse report team, I have been waiting for over 3 months and there is no answer, their Abuse report team doesn't do their job, also if they did, the attacker simply creates another account and starts attacking me again, this guy won't stop, I wanted to know if there is any solution that I can do at my end to block all OVH IP ranges without having my bandwitdth saturated.

Comment: And yes, the DDoS attack is from the same hosting company (OVH), these guys just keep creating new accounts, buying servers and attacking mine.

Comment: Nope, no way. They should at least allow isolating your servers in the network - given these are game servers, there is no reason servers from different clients can talk to each other.

Comment: I mean, I have a dedicated server (root access), but other OVH servers are not filtered by OVH's firewall, so they're able to bypass any OVH filtering and directly affect my server saturating my bandwitdht.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing you can do. You don't control the upstream infrastructure, so you can't drop packets before they reach you.

Comment: Hi, I have a dedicated server (root access), but other OVH servers are not filtered by OVH's firewall, so they're able to bypass any OVH filtering and directly affect my server saturating my bandwitdht. Is there really nothing to do? Like null routing OVH IP ranges?

Comment: As long as you don't control upstream, you ***can't*** stop packets from entering the pipe to your server. Null route all you want on your end; when you discard the data they will already have filled your pipe.

Comment: Thanks man, I think I'll need to look for another dedicated server provider. After so many year being OVH customer, it's incredible how their support doesn't care and only want you to wait until Report abuse team answer (They have over 3 months without answering my report).

Comment: They may not be answering because they consider the question to be "beneath" them, but that's still not ok. You generally shouldn't expect a response from abuse contacts. A lot of the time, they are unmonitored, and the rest of the time they are so inundated with spam/malicious traffic that legitimate requests slip through the cracks. Also, there's really not much they can do for you, either. They don't control the internet. They just give you a server with a pipe to it. You could purchase their game DDoS protection service, but, aside from that, you're basically on your own.